# Why can't I open DMG files which reside on a read-only NFS filesystem?

Tags: macos, dmg, nfs

I've discovered a strange problem... if I have disk image files (DMGs) which reside on a read-only NFS share, I cannot open these in Mac OS X 10.7.5. The same files open fine when accessed over AFP. However, trying to open them using `hdiutil attach` when they're on the NFS share results in "attach failed - Read-only file system":

```
bash-3.2# /usr/bin/hdiutil attach /Volumes/nfs_share/Some.dmg
hdiutil: attach failed - Read-only file system
```

**Even if the AFP share is read-only, I can attach those same images.** But for some reason, a read-only *NFS* share doesn't work.

Ultimately what I *want* to do is attach the images *with a shadow file*, to mount the read-only images as read-write. But this also fails the same way:

```
bash-3.2# /usr/bin/hdiutil attach /Volumes/nfs_share/Some.dmg -mountpoint /Somewhere -shadow /path/to/Some-Shadow
hdiutil: attach failed - Read-only file system
```

Again, this works perfectly if the image is served via AFP. It also works fine if the NFS share is read-write, but for security reasons I cannot do that.

**How can I mount DMG files which reside on a read-only NFS share?**

---

**Additional information:**

The relevant line from `/etc/exports` on the FreeNAS (FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p7) server:

```
/mnt/raid/netboot -alldirs -ro -mapall=netboot:netboot -network 10.100.0.0/16
```

The output of `/usr/bin/hdiutil attach -verbose /Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg -notremovable -shadow /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow -owners on -noverify -noautofsck -nobrowse`:

```
Initializing…
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe stat() failed.  No such file or directory.
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score        1, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
Attaching…
Error 30 (Read-only file system).
Finishing…
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 30
hdiutil: attach failed - Read-only file system
```

Output of `rpcinfo -p` on the NFS Server:

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4 local    111  rpcbind
    100000    3 local    111  rpcbind
    100000    2 local    111  rpcbind
    100005    1   udp    967  mountd
    100005    3   udp    967  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    967  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    967  mountd
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100024    1   udp    689  status
    100024    1   tcp    689  status
    100021    0   udp    616  nlockmgr
    100021    0   tcp    927  nlockmgr
    100021    1   udp    616  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp    927  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp    616  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp    927  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp    616  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp    927  nlockmgr
```

Output of `mount` on the Mac OS X 10.7.5 client:

```
/dev/disk1s2 on / (hfs, local)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
afp_0egBhf12TAP01SptRt47XSdj-3.2c000002 on /private/var/netboot (afpfs, nobrowse)
afp_0egBhf12TAP01SptRt47XSdj-4.2c000004 on /Network/Applications (afpfs, read-only)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
afp_0egBhf12TAP01SptRt47XSdj-4.2c000008 on /Network/Servers/chef.farcry.sitepalette.com/Users (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse, mounted by jnet)
afp_0egBhf12TAP01SptRt47XSdj-4.2c000009 on /Volumes/Users (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by jnet)
10.100.1.2:/mnt/raid/netboot on /Volumes/netboot (nfs)
```

And finally, the output of `/usr/bin/hdiutil attach -debug /Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg -notremovable -shadow /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow -owners on -noverify -noautofsck -nobrowse`:

```
calling DIHLDiskImageAttach with 
skip-verify: true
auto-fsck: false
drive-options:
quiet: false
shadow-url: file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
mount-nobrowse: true
enable-owners: true
verbose: false
debug: true
agent: hdiutil
fixed-disk: true
image-options:
main-url: file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
2012-11-27 12:02:23.053 hdiutil[23401:707] DIHLDiskImageAttach: input dictionary {
    agent = hdiutil;
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" =     {
    };
    "enable-owners" = 1;
    "fixed-disk" = 1;
    "image-options" =     {
    };
    "main-url" = "file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg";
    "mount-nobrowse" = 1;
    quiet = 0;
    "shadow-url" = "file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow";
    "skip-verify" = 1;
    verbose = 0;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.054 hdiutil[23401:707] DIHLDiskImageAttach: disabling legacy image format attach
2012-11-27 12:02:23.055 hdiutil[23401:707] DIHLDiskImageAttach: newImagekeys = {
    "legacy-disabled" = 1;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.055 hdiutil[23401:707] DIHLDiskImageAttach: creating DIHelperProxy
2012-11-27 12:02:23.056 hdiutil[23401:707] with dictionary: {
    agent = hdiutil;
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" = <62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 01010000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0009>;
    "enable-owners" = 1;
    "fixed-disk" = 1;
    "image-options" = <62706c69 73743030 d101025f 100f6c65 67616379 2d646973 61626c65 6409080b 1d000000 00000001 01000000 00000000 03000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 1e>;
    "main-url" = "file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg";
    "mount-nobrowse" = 1;
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    quiet = 0;
    "shadow-url" = "file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow";
    "skip-verify" = 1;
    verbose = 0;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.056 hdiutil[23401:707] [DIHelperProxy alloc]
2012-11-27 12:02:23.056 hdiutil[23401:707] [DIHelperProxy alloc] returning self 0x7fa39b00d690, retainCount 1
2012-11-27 12:02:23.057 hdiutil[23401:707] DIHLDiskImageAttach: running DIHelperProxy
2012-11-27 12:02:23.057 hdiutil[23401:707] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.057 hdiutil[23401:707] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] detaching thread
2012-11-27 12:02:23.058 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.058 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] setting up server
2012-11-27 12:02:23.059 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.059 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] setting up _headerConnection
2012-11-27 12:02:23.060 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] setting up _headerConnection rootObject
2012-11-27 12:02:23.060 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] adding NSConnectionDidInitializeNotification notification
2012-11-27 12:02:23.061 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] exiting
2012-11-27 12:02:23.061 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] launching
2012-11-27 12:02:23.061 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.063 hdiutil[23401:2803] launching helper tool at "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/diskimages-helper".
2012-11-27 12:02:23.063 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] adding NSTaskDidTerminateNotification notification
2012-11-27 12:02:23.063 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy thread LaunchToolAuthenticated] launching
2012-11-27 12:02:23.065 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] exiting
2012-11-27 12:02:23.065 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] running runloop
2012-11-27 12:02:23.081 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.081 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] adding new NSConnectionDidDieNotification notification
2012-11-27 12:02:23.081 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] removing old NSConnectionDidDieNotification notification
2012-11-27 12:02:23.082 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] removing old connection rootObject
2012-11-27 12:02:23.082 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] invalidating old connection
2012-11-27 12:02:23.083 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] releasing old connection
2012-11-27 12:02:23.083 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] and replacing with new connection
2012-11-27 12:02:23.083 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy helperConnectionInitialized] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.085 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy connectToFramework] entry, helper 0x7fa39b016940
2012-11-27 12:02:23.085 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy connectToFramework] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.186 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.187 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] starting operation with helper
2012-11-27 12:02:23.190 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.194 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: initialize
Initializing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2012-11-27 12:02:23.199 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.201 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] updateImageAndDriveDictionaries: before update _imageOptions: {
    "enable-keychain" = 1;
    writeable = 0;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.201 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] updateImageAndDriveDictionaries: _imageOptions: {
    "enable-keychain" = 1;
    "legacy-disabled" = 1;
    writeable = 0;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.202 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] _driveOptions: {
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    autodiskmount = 1;
    removable = 0;
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.202 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: initializing framework
2012-11-27 12:02:23.202 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] {
    agent = hdiutil;
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    "auto-fsck-failure-override-type" = callback;
    "auto-open-ro-root" = 0;
    "auto-open-rw-root" = 0;
    "auto-stretch" = 0;
    "bundlebs-checkpointing" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonflush" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonidle" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonsleep" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localfdcount" = 6;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonflush" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonidle" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonsleep" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotefdcount" = 3;
    "burn-apple-supported-devices-only" = 0;
    "burn-no-underrun-protection" = 0;
    "burn-synthesize-content" = 1;
    "bzip2-level" = 0;
    "callback-with-sla" = 1;
    debug = 1;
    "disable-encrypted-images" = 0;
    "disable-kernel-mounting" = 1;
    "disable-owners" = 0;
    "drive-options" = <62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 01010000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0009>;
    "enable-owners" = 1;
    "filevault-default-case-sensitive-file-system" = "Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+";
    "filevault-default-encryption-type" = "AES-128";
    "filevault-default-file-system" = "Journaled HFS+";
    "filevault-default-image-type" = SPARSEBUNDLE;
    "filevault-default-partition-type" = SPUD;
    "filevault-default-volume-name" = FileVault;
    "fixed-disk" = 1;
    "force-idme" = 0;
    "hfsplus-stretch-parameters" =     {
        "hfsplus-stretch-allocation-block-size" = 4096;
        "hfsplus-stretch-allocation-file-size" = 8388608;
        "hfsplus-stretch-threshold" = 524288;
    };
    "idle-timeout" = 15;
    "ifd-format" = UDZO;
    "ifd-ignore-io-errors" = 1;
    "ifd-segment-size" = 0;
    "iff-format" = UDZO;
    "iff-fs" = "HFS+";
    "iff-layout" = SPUD;
    "iff-source-owners" = auto;
    "iff-spotlight-indexing" = 0;
    "iff-temp-sparse-band-size" = 20480;
    "iff-temp-use-rw-if-possible" = 1;
    "iff-usehelper" = 1;
    "ignore-bad-checksums" = 0;
    "image-options" = <62706c69 73743030 d101025f 100f6c65 67616379 2d646973 61626c65 6409080b 1d000000 00000001 01000000 00000000 03000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 1e>;
    "main-url" = "file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg";
    "mount-attempted" = 1;
    "mount-nobrowse" = 1;
    "mount-point" = "/Volumes/";
    "mount-private" = 0;
    "mount-required" = 1;
    "mount-type" = in;
    "nbi-spotlight-indexing" = 0;
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    "progress-delay" = 5;
    "pthread-reader-cap" = 4;
    quiet = 0;
    "reauthenticate-upon-wake" = 1;
    "shadow-url" = "file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow";
    "skip-auto-fsck-for-system-images" = 1;
    "skip-idme" = 1;
    "skip-idme-reveal" = 0;
    "skip-idme-trash" = 0;
    "skip-previously-verified" = 1;
    "skip-sla" = 0;
    "skip-verify" = 1;
    "skip-verify-locked" = 0;
    "skip-verify-remote" = 1;
    "sparsebundle-compactonidle" = 0;
    "suppress-uiagent" = 1;
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
    "use-compressed-xml" = 0;
    "use-keychain" = 1;
    verbose = 0;
    "zlib-level" = 1;
}
DILoadDriver: checking for disk image driver
DILoadDriver: DI_kextExists() returned 0x00000000 (0)
DIIsInitialized: returning NO
2012-11-27 12:02:23.206 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.206 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] imageURL file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
2012-11-27 12:02:23.206 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] shadowURL file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
2012-11-27 12:02:23.207 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] sectionStart (null) sectionLength (null)
2012-11-27 12:02:23.207 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: setting legacy-disabled to 1
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
skip-permissions-check: true
legacy-disabled: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
skip-permissions-check: true
legacy-disabled: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CCarbonBackingStore
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe: setting initial rval to +100
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg).CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for 
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 6 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setNoFollow: setting _noFollow to 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 0
2012-11-27 12:02:23.208 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: resolving file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg returned 0
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
skip-permissions-check: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
skip-permissions-check: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 1 for file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CCarbonBackingStore
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe stat() failed.  No such file or directory.
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow).CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for 
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 6 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 2
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 2
DIResolveURLToBackingStore: unable to resolve to any backing store class. 2. 
2012-11-27 12:02:23.208 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: resolving shadow file://localhost/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow returned 2
2012-11-27 12:02:23.208 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: resolving disk image
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
legacy-disabled: true
writeable: false
enable-keychain: true
image-path: /Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
legacy-disabled: true
writeable: false
enable-keychain: true
image-path: /Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CCarbonBackingStore
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe: setting initial rval to +100
CCarbonBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg).CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for 
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 6 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file://localhost/Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setPermission: opening /Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: mapping flags 0x00000000 -> 0x00000014 (locks are MANDATORY)
CBSDBackingStore:OpenLockFriendly: could not open with lock 30
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 30
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 30
DIResolveURLToBackingStore: unable to resolve to any backing store class. 30. 
DIResolveURLToDiskImage: resolving backing store/file encoding failed. 30. 
2012-11-27 12:02:23.211 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: attach
Attaching…
Error 30 (Read-only file system).
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2012-11-27 12:02:23.227 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.228 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: cleanup
Finishing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2012-11-27 12:02:23.228 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.229 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] DIHelperAttach performOperation: returning 30
2012-11-27 12:02:23.229 diskimages-helper[23407:2503] -decrementBackgroundThreadCount: _backgroundThreadCount is now 0.
2012-11-27 12:02:23.229 diskimages-helper[23407:303] DIHelper _report_results: reporting {
    payload =     {
    };
    "result-code" = 30;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.230 hdiutil[23401:2803] reportResultsToFramework: proxy has finished operation
2012-11-27 12:02:23.230 hdiutil[23401:2803] reportResultsToFramework: results are: {
    payload =     {
    };
    "result-code" = 30;
}
2012-11-27 12:02:23.230 hdiutil[23401:2803] reportResultsToFramework: _threadResultsError is 30
2012-11-27 12:02:23.231 hdiutil[23401:2803] reportResultsToFramework: disconnecting from helper.
2012-11-27 12:02:23.231 diskimages-helper[23407:303] -setCanTerminate: main thread can exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.332 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.333 hdiutil[23401:2803] disconnectFromHelper: removing observers
2012-11-27 12:02:23.333 hdiutil[23401:2803] disconnectFromHelper: terminating proxy
2012-11-27 12:02:23.334 diskimages-helper[23407:303] DIHelper: terminateHelper: entry.
2012-11-27 12:02:23.334 hdiutil[23401:2803] disconnectFromHelper: terminated proxy
2012-11-27 12:02:23.335 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] releasing helper
2012-11-27 12:02:23.335 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] exit
2012-11-27 12:02:23.435 diskimages-helper[23407:303] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] entry
2012-11-27 12:02:23.435 diskimages-helper[23407:303] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] releasing connection
2012-11-27 12:02:23.435 diskimages-helper[23407:303] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] releasing frameworkProxy
2012-11-27 12:02:23.435 diskimages-helper[23407:303] -DIHelperAgentMaster terminateUIAgentConnection.
2012-11-27 12:02:23.435 diskimages-helper[23407:303] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] marking _frameworkDisconnected
2012-11-27 12:02:23.435 diskimages-helper[23407:303] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] exiting
2012-11-27 12:02:24.232 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] removing NSConnectionDidDieNotification observers
2012-11-27 12:02:24.233 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] removing NSConnectionDidInitializeNotification observers
2012-11-27 12:02:24.234 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] removing NSTaskDidTerminateNotification observers
2012-11-27 12:02:24.234 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadRunRunLoop] invalidating connection
2012-11-27 12:02:24.235 diskimages-helper[23407:303] DIHelper dealloc.
2012-11-27 12:02:24.234 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy threadRunRunLoop] releasing connection
2012-11-27 12:02:24.235 diskimages-helper[23407:303] -DIHelperAgentMaster terminateUIAgentConnection.
2012-11-27 12:02:24.235 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] after running runloop
2012-11-27 12:02:24.235 diskimages-helper[23407:303] helper: child_after_exec returning 0
2012-11-27 12:02:24.235 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] waiting for task to terminate to avoid zombies
2012-11-27 12:02:24.236 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] releasing task
2012-11-27 12:02:24.236 hdiutil[23401:2803] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] exiting
2012-11-27 12:02:24.236 hdiutil[23401:707] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] returning 30
2012-11-27 12:02:24.237 hdiutil[23401:707] DIHLDiskImageAttach: DIHelperProxy returned 30
2012-11-27 12:02:24.237 hdiutil[23401:707] [DIHelperProxy dealloc]
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 30
hdiutil: attach failed - Read-only file system
kyle:~ root#
```

Comment: I don't have an NFS share to test with, but I would try to have a quiet system and run `fs_usage` to see if I can catch the filesystem making a write call - possibly filing a bug with Apple. It seems you should be able to read a read-only DMG - but perhaps there is some deeper technical reason why it's failing and the OS needs a better error message to inform us why...

Comment: Good idea @bmike! Also, I ran `hdiutil` with the `-debug` switch, I can post those logs here

Comment: Indeed - make an answer with whatever you find and we can team up - report a bug or edit the answer as we pick apart the "why".

Comment: Which OS runs on the NFS server? What is the output of `rpcinfo -p` on the server? What is the output of `mount` on your Mac? Can you also add the relevant line of `/etc/exports` on the NFS server to the question?

Comment: @jaume the NFS server is a FreeNAS (FreeBSD) server. I'll add those items to the question tomorrow.

Comment: I've set up an NFS server (Ubuntu 12.04) with a read-only export that I mounted on my Mac (OS X 10.8.2) and I couldn't reproduce your problem (I tested all dmg formats: readonly, compressed, encrypted, etc)... Could you add the output of `hdiutil -debug` and the information I asked for to your question?

Comment: @jaume Apologies for the delay. I have added all the information you requested. I don't have a 10.8 system to test on, I'm running 10.7. Maybe this is an issue which was fixed in 10.8...

Comment: Thanks for all the information, I could reproduce the problem. I had exactly the same error message. I think the shadow file specified in `-shadow` can't be created, it is located in `/private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow` which is read-only (unless you changed permissions). Why don't you create a shadow folder: `mkdir ~/.shadowfolder/` and specify it with option `-shadow ~/.shadowfolder/image.dmg.shadow`? Can you try and report back?

Comment: @jaume Hm. `/private/var/netboot` is a mounted AFP share, and root has access to it. I can `touch /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow` perfectly fine... and if I try to place the shadow file anywhere else it still fails...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been interested in this question since Nov 2012 and even set up a FreeNAS VM to reproduce the issue.

I eventually gave up but since the question has been resuscitated **I will share what I found out back then and in the last hours (luckily I didn't delete the VM) and what I think the cause for this issue is. I have also found a workaround.**

### My setup

First of all, this is my test setup:

- OS X 10.8.2 (sorry, no 10.7.5 around).
- FreeNAS (FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p1)

  [image]

  (The OP's version is FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p7 - I couldn't find the same version.)
- A NAS filesystem in `/mnt/raid`:

  [image]
- A user named `netboot`:

  [image]
- An AFP filesystem (`/mnt/raid/netboot`) exported as `netboot`:

  [image]

  (Note that it is configured read-only).
- An NFS filesystem (same path as AFP filesystem, to match the OP's configuration: `/mnt/raid/netboot`):

  [image]

### AFP works, NFS doesn't

I mounted the AFP read-only filesystem as user `netboot` using the Finder with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>:

[image]

and mounted a DMG image file without any problems:

```
$ sudo rm /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
$ sudo /usr/bin/hdiutil attach /Volumes/netboot/p7zip-9.04-0.i386.dmg -notremovable -shadow /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow -owners on -noverify -noautofsck -nobrowse
Password:
/dev/disk3              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk3s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk3s2            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/p7zip.pkg
```

Then I unmounted it and mounted the read-only NFS filesystem (I also used <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) and couldn't mount the DMG image file.

I think the problem is logged here:

```
CBSDBackingStore::setPermission: opening /Volumes/netboot/Lion.nbi/Library.dmg
CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: mapping flags 0x00000000 -> 0x00000014 (locks are MANDATORY)
CBSDBackingStore:OpenLockFriendly: could not open with lock 30
```

Error 30 means (see `man 2 intro`):

> 30 EROFS Read-only file system.  An attempt was made to modify a file
>   or directory was made on a file system that was read-only at the time.

No surprise here, it is indeed a read-only filesystem, but... when mounted over AFP it works, why?

Because Apple's NFS implementation has some problems with locking. As stated [in this post](http://gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users/2011-March/006937.html) at gluster.org:

> OS X does a phenominal amount of file locking (some would say,
>   needlessly so) and has always been really sensitive to the
>   configuration of locking on the NFS servers. So much so that if you
>   randomly pick an NFS server in a large enterprise, true success is
>   pretty unlikely.

In my setup, the NFS server (that is, the FreeNAS VM) was suddenly irresponsive (from my Mac's `/var/log/system.log`):

```
Mar 15 15:35:04 avallone.local rpc.lockd[8119]: Lockd got unexpected signal 20
Mar 15 15:35:04 avallone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lockd[8119]): Exited with code: 1
Mar 15 15:35:04 avallone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lockd): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
(...)
Mar 15 15:35:07 avallone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.statd[8121]): Exited with code: 1
Mar 15 15:35:07 avallone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.statd): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
Mar 15 15:35:13 avallone kernel[0]: nfs server 172.16.54.186:/mnt/raid/netboot: lockd not responding
Mar 15 15:35:13 avallone.local KernelEventAgent[72]: tid 00000000 received event(s) VQ_NOTRESP (1)
Mar 15 15:35:13 avallone.local KernelEventAgent[72]: tid 00000000 type 'nfs', mounted on '/Volumes/netboot', from '172.16.54.186:/mnt/raid/netboot', not responding
(...)
Mar 15 15:35:34 avallone.local KernelEventAgent[72]: tid 00000000 unmounting 1 filesystems
```

The output of `sudo /usr/bin/hdiutil attach -debug /Volumes/netboot/p7zip-9.04-0.i386.dmg -notremovable -shadow /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow -owners on -noverify -noautofsck -nobrowse` was:

```
CBSDBackingStore::setPermission: opening /Volumes/netboot/p7zip-9.04-0.i386.dmg
CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: mapping flags 0x00000000 -> 0x00000014 (locks are MANDATORY)
CBSDBackingStore:OpenLockFriendly: could not open with lock 5
```

Error 5 means (again from `man 2 intro`):

> 5 EIO Input/output error.  Some physical input or output error
>   occurred.  This error will not be reported until a subsequent
>   operation on the same file descriptor and may be lost (over written)
>   by any subsequent errors.

which isn't suprising at all, the NFS filesystem was gone.

### Workaround

A workaround (tested on OS X 10.8) is to mount NFS with options `nolocks,locallocks`. As explained in the post at gluster.org already mentioned:

> Fortunately, there is a fix: just turn off network locking. You can do
>   it by adding the "nolocks,locallocks" options in the advanced options
>   field of the Disk Utility NFS mounting UI, but this is painful if you
>   do a lot of them, and doesn't help at all with /net. You can edit
>   /etc/auto_master to add these options to the /net entry, but it
>   doesn't affect other mounts - however I do recommend deleting the
>   hidefromfinder option in auto_master. If you want to fix every
>   automount, edit /etc/autofs.conf and search for the line that starts
>   with AUTOMOUNTD_MNTOPTS=. These options get applied on every mount.
>   Add nolocks,locallocks and your world will be faster and happier after
>   you reboot.

I manually mounted `172.16.54.186:/mnt/raid/netboot` and it worked flawlessly:

```
$ sudo rm /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
$ sudo mount -o nolocks,locallocks,ro 172.16.54.186:/mnt/raid/netboot /tmp/mnt
$ sudo /usr/bin/hdiutil attach /tmp/mnt/p7zip-9.04-0.i386.dmg -notremovable -shadow /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow -owners on -noverify -noautofsck -nobrowse
/dev/disk6              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk6s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk6s2            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/p7zip.pkg
```

I also edited `/etc/auto_master` like this:

```
+auto_master # Use directory service
#/net             -hosts    -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/net              -hosts    -nosuid,nolocks,locallocks
/home             auto_home -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers  -fstab
/-                -static
```

stopped and started `automountd` and `autofsd`:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.automountd.plist 
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.autofsd.plist 
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.autofsd.plist 
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.automountd.plist
```

and worked like a charm:

```
$ cd /net/172.16.54.186/mnt/raid/netboot
$ ls 
Network Trash Folder  Temporary Items  p7zip-9.04-0.i386.dmg
$ sudo rm /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow
$ sudo /usr/bin/hdiutil attach p7zip-9.04-0.i386.dmg -notremovable -shadow /private/var/netboot/Library-Shadow -owners on -noverify -noautofsck -nobrowse
/dev/disk7              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk7s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk7s2            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/p7zip.pkg
```

Comment: Awesome, what a good read.

Comment: Wow this is fantastic, Thanks! I will test this over the weekend, it might solve my issue!

Comment: Thanks jaume, this worked like a charm! Unfortunately I have already found an alternative and no longer need to mount this same DMG with a shadow file, but `nolocks,locallocks` is helping NFS performance of other read-only NFS shares with DMG files, so thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm happy the workaround worked in your environment. Although you don't need it anymore,   it's nice to know *why* something doesn't work, isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely, and now I know what I need to change should I need this again in the future! (The goal previously was to place the `/Library` of our NetBoot image n a RAID array. We no longer need this as we purchased a new Mac Pro server)

Answer (score -1):

## hdiutil attach -readonly …

For an image that's stored on a read-only file system, I reckon that `-readonly` should be used at time of attachment.

(The AFP case may be exceptional.)

---

Considering the down vote and the comment from @Josh: I misunderstood the `-shadow` part of the man page for `hdiutil`:

> … allows read-only images to be attached read/write …

– I imagined that `-shadow` could override `-readonly`.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. I wanted to attache a read-only image as a read-write volume with a shadow file.

Comment: Regarding your edit, no, using both `-readonly` and `-shadow` would read from a shadow file but mount the image read-only. So for example it would allow you to read changes made to a shadow file without updating that shadow file. The issue was NFS locks as jaume discovered.

Comment: A very neat explanation from @Josh – thanks! I'll leave this answer so that other readers don't make the same mistake as me.